# How do i download videos which have duration more than certain time( like 10 minutes ) from youtube playlist using youtube-dl?

Tags: download, youtube-dl

I want to download the videos which are more than 10 minutes from 
 youtube playlist

Answer (score 5):

```
yotube-dl --extract-audio --match-filter "duration > 600" -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" <url to playlist>
```

The youtube-dl --help page is your friend.

Comment: Instead of playlist could it be the channel?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein have you tried just replacing the playlist url with the channel url?

Comment: Thanks! And how would you download the top 10 recent ones?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein maybe ```--playlist-end 10```? Try reading the manual in case it doesn't work https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/youtube-dl.1.html